# Maintain tab order on keyup and keydown

Tags: wpf, tabs, navigation, key

i am new to WPF and in my application I want to maintain tab order through navigation keys(up/down arrow keys). so i iterate each control in grid on window load event and add delegate as following

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (UIElement element in gridChild.Children)
            {
                if (element.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                {
                    TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)element;
                    tb1.PreviewKeyUp += TextBox_KeyDown;
                }
                else if (element.GetType() == typeof(PasswordBox))
                {
                    PasswordBox tb1 = (PasswordBox)element;
                    tb1.PreviewKeyUp += TextBox_KeyDown;
                }
                else if (element.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                {
                    Button tb1 = (Button)element;
                    tb1.PreviewKeyDown += TextBox_KeyDown;
                }
            }
}
```

and handler is following

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Down || (e.Key == Key.Enter && sender.GetType()!=typeof(Button))  )
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                UIElement focusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
                if (focusedElement != null)
                {
                    focusedElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
                }



            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Up)
            {



                e.Handled = true;
                UIElement focusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
                if (focusedElement != null)
                {
                    focusedElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Previous));
                }
            }
        }
```

its works well when i use navigation keys except one issue.Issue is that when Press up or down navigation keys on Button, then it skip one textbox which are next in tab order. I am not sure that what is wrong with above code. Please suggest what should I do for maintain tab order through navigation keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TabOrder is called so because focus is switched between controls with Tab key, not arrow keys. Your problems are caused by the fact that some controls may suppress arrow key events, such as TextBox in your case. But actually you can overcome this by adding event handler this way:

```
textBox.AddHandler(TextBox.KeyDownEvent, 
                   new KeyEventHandler(TextBox_KeyDown), 
                   handledEventsToo: true);
```

TextBox handles arrow keys down events because it uses those keys in text navigation. So the TextBox handles them (moves the caret) and sets `e.Handled = true`, which stops the event from [bubbling up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies) - that's why you don't catch this event.

But as I said, navigating focus with arrow keys may be frustrating to user. You can navigate with Tab key. WPF fully supports this approach and even sets the tab indexes itself, so that focus is moved from left to right and then from top to bottom of the window as user presses Tab key. You can prevent control from being focused with Tab key by setting its `IsTabStop` property to false. Also you can define your own tab order by setting elements' `TabIndex` property. No code at all is needed to make this approach work.

One more reason for you to prefer this approach to one that you implemented is that your code is hard to maintain. Look at your `Window_Loaded` handler. What if you add some controls to this window in future? You will have not to forget to add code there too. What if new window appears in your application? You will have to duplicate this block of code.